# how to read all file names from a given directory using perl?

Tags: perl, foreach, chomp

friends i 've this code which read file name from a directory and print those names

```
opendir DIR1,  "defaults" or die "cannot open dir: $!";#open the given dir
        my @default_files=readdir DIR1;
        foreach my $fls(@default_files){ 
                        chomp($fls); 
                        print "$fls\n";
           }
```

when i run the above code i've got

```
.
..
PGR.csv
report.csv
std_headers.csv
tab_name.txt
```

'm confused what is first two lines?
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't `chomp` the filenames returned by `readdir`. Every character in a filename corresponds to something that is *in the name* of the file in the underlying file system. Instead, use something like `print qq{'$fls'\n}` so one can tell apart filenames with trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler alternative can be using the `glob` function:

```
my @default_files = glob 'defaults/*';
```

Or:

```
my @default_files = <defaults/*>;
```

These functions filter out file and directory entries that begin with `.`, just like the shell does.

Answer (score 1):

The first to lines are:

- `.` link to the directory you are currently visiting.
- `..` link to the directory above the directory (parent directory) you are visiting.

**EDIT:**

One possibility to filter out both named entries would be using `grep`:

```
opendir DIR1, "tmp" or die "cannot open dir: $!";
my @default_files= grep { ! /^\.\.?$/ } readdir  DIR1;

foreach my $fls (@default_files) { 
   chomp($fls); 
   print "$fls\n";
}
```

Comment: Probably the most simple solution would be to just filter the unwanted candidates out after reading the entries as given in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

"." means the present working directory and ".." means the parent directory of the present working directory

Answer (score 0):

In a directory listing, `.` stands for [Working Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) and `..` stands for [Parent Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_directory#The_folder_metaphor).

In scalar context, you can skip those entries by explicitly checking for them:

```
while (defined(my $next = readdir $dir)) {
    next if $next =~ /\A[.][.]?\z/;
    # ...
}
```

or in list context:

```
my @entries = grep !/\A[.][.]?\z/, readdir $dir;
```

If I am already using [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSlurp), I prefer to just use the `read_dir` function it provides. The following will automatically skip `.` and `..` in addition to prepending the path to the directory to each returned entry:

```
 my @paths = read_dir('/path/to/dir', prefix => 1);
```